# Need to fetch chat from database in a sequence

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I am working on a chat plugin custom made by me.
Here is my db structure for chat table

```
+----+----+----+------+------+------+-------+
| ID | FR | TO | TEXT | TIME | FLAG | EMAIL |
+----+----+----+------+------+------+-------+
```

Now I need to fetch the chat using ajax but it is not fetching in a sequence in which it was created. 
Here is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `j18h_user_chat` WHERE `fr` = '$nm' AND `to` = '$name' ORDER BY time";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE `fr` = '$name' AND `to` = '$nm' ORDER BY time";

$abc = $wpdb->get_results($query);
$abc2 = $wpdb->get_results($query2);

echo "<div class='log'><div class='lef'>";

foreach ($abc as $key )
{
    echo '<div class="ui-chatbox-msg left" style="display: block; max-width: 285px;"><b><img class="usr" src="'.$key->email.'">  </b><span>'.$key->text.'</span></div>';
}

echo "</div><div class='rig'>";

foreach ($abc2 as $key2 )
{
    echo '<div class="ui-chatbox-msg right" style="display: block; max-width: 285px;"><b><img class="usr" src="'.$key2->email.'">  </b><span>'.$key2->text.'</span></div>';
}
```

Here the messages are stored one by one.
In first query I am fetching messages which i typed and in second which user typed.
So can anyone tell me how to fetch the chat in same sequence as it was created.

Comment: Are `j18h_user_chat` and `$table` the same table?

Comment: yes they are the same table.

Comment: Then why have two queries? Just stick an `OR` in your `WHERE`. i.e ``WHERE (`fr` = $nm AND `to` = $name) OR (`fr` = $name AND `to` = $nm) `` Unless there is something I'm not getting...

Comment: In first query the chat sent from current user is retrieved while in the second query the chat from other user is fetched.
The chat from current user is fetched in `ui-chatbox-msg left` while from other user chat is fetched in `ui-chatbox-msg right` class.

Comment: okay thanks i  added OR and it was perfect but still one question . I am fetching data using `foreach` loop. Now the problem is all chat is fetched once. Now i want to apply condition if message is from current user add class `left` or if it is from other user add class`right`. Here is my new code (thanks to you) :  `foreach ($abc as $key ) {
    echo '<div class="ui-chatbox-msg left" style="display: block; max-width: 285px;"><b><img class="usr" src="'.$key->email.'">  </b><span>'.$key->text.'</span></div>';   } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
SELECT * FROM `j18h_user_chat` 
WHERE (`fr` = '$nm' AND `to` = '$name') OR (`fr` = '$name' AND `to` = '$nm')
ORDER BY time
```

Then to determine what class (`left` or `right`) to add to your div, something like this may work.  (**Note:** I'm going under the impression `$nm` is the current user)

```
foreach($abc as $key)
{
    echo '<div class="ui-chatbox-msg '. leftOrRight($key->fr, $nm) .'" style="display: block; max-width: 285px;"><b><img class="usr" src="'.$key->email.'">  </b><span>'.$key->text.'</span></div>';
}

function leftOrRight($from, $currentUser)
{
    return ($from == $currentUser) ? "left" : "right";
}
```